# How to create an IAM role for AWS Glue using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to create an IAM role using terraform, so that i can handle setup the other Amazon Glue infrastructure. For example, i will use this role to run a crawler or rin a notepad ! Here is the Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
  name = "test_role"

  # Terraform's "jsonencode" function converts a
  # Terraform expression result to valid JSON syntax.
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Sid" : "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : "glue:*",
        Principal = {
          Service = "glue.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "Sid" : "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : "iam:PassRole",
        Principal = {
          Service = "glue.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

However, when i run the above code, i face with the below error:

```
│ Error: failed creating IAM Role (test_role): MalformedPolicyDocument: AssumeRole policy may only specify STS AssumeRole actions.
│       status code: 400, request id: 2e7c7190-525b-41ca-9840-ac13d22a35f8
│
│   with aws_iam_role.test_role,
│   on glue-crawler.tf line 5, in resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role":
│    5: resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
```

I will be thankful if you help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: The policy you have should be assigned to `inline_policy`. You will still need an `assume_role_policy`. If you plan to attach this role to an ec2 instance via an instance-profile, you can copy the policy from the basic example in the TF docs https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role#basic-example

Comment: i tried your hint, however i did not get the result. 
can you please write an anwer ?

Answer (score 0):

The role must be assumed by some entity (IAM user, other role or AWS service). So `assume_role_policy` specifics which entity can assume the role. However, what permissions are after the role has been assumed, can be provided using `inline_policies`. For example:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
  name = "test_role"

  # Terraform's "jsonencode" function converts a
  # Terraform expression result to valid JSON syntax.
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Sid" : "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : "sts:AssumeRole",
        Principal = {
          Service = "glue.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  })
  
  inline_policy {
    name   = "Allow-s3"
    policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Sid" : "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : "glue:*",
        Principal = {
          Service = "glue.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "Sid" : "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : "iam:PassRole",
        Principal = {
          Service = "glue.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    ]      
    })  
  }
  
}
```

You may need to adjust `assume_role_policy` as its not clear for the question which entity (IAM user, other role or AWS service) can assume the role. The above role as defined, can only be assumed by a glue service, not IAM users, nor other AWS services (e.g. EC2 instance or lambda function).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. 
However, i noticed that my main issue is not resolved. i will be really thankful, if you look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76202467/creating-inline-policy-allow-s3-malformedpolicydocument-policy-document-shou

Answer (score 0):

Policy documents should not have a principal. I suspect what you are looking for is:

```json
resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
  name = "test_role"

  # Terraform's "jsonencode" function converts a
  # Terraform expression result to valid JSON syntax.
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Sid" : "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : "sts:AssumeRole",
        Principal = {
          Service = "glue.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  })

  inline_policy {
    name = "Allow-s3"
    policy = jsonencode({
      "Version" : "2012-10-17",
      "Statement" : [
        {
          "Sid" : "VisualEditor0",
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Action" : "s3:*",
          "Resource" : "*"
        }
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

which is a role which has full s3 permissions for any resource that can be assumed by the glue service.

Comment: i get the below error:
`Error: error creating Glue crawler: InvalidInputException: Service is unable to assume provided role. Please verify role's TrustPolicy` . i will be thankful if you move your answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76202467/creating-inline-policy-allow-s3-malformedpolicydocument-policy-document-shou?noredirect=1#comment134393444_76202467 because then your answer makes more sense. is it because of bounty which you moved your answer here ? if yes, i will set a bunty there too.

Comment: @Jeff can you clarify when you see that error? it's not at the terraform provisioning time, is it?

Comment: it happened when i run `terraform apply -auto-approve`. it failed to create my crawler.

Comment: @Jeff can you add the relevant terraform code to your question? because the code I shared for creating the role works fine, so it must be something else

Comment: @Polo, the terraform code is the same as in this link. i try to add them here .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76202467/creating-inline-policy-allow-s3-malformedpolicydocument-policy-document-shou

Comment: @Jeff I created the bucket, glue catalog and glue crawler, and the role I shared in my answer all successfully